# Pandas loading an old version of Excel file into a dataframe

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, pandas

In my module I have:

```
excel_location = r'C:\path\to\excelfile.xlsx'
test = pandas.io.excel.read_excel(excel_location)
print(test)
```

I edited the Excel file at this location(opened, saved, closed), but Pandas keeps printing data from the *old* version of that file. If I move the file out of the folder I get the expected `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` error, but if I put it back in I get the same old data back. I've also tried restarting my machine to clear any temp files... Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: using windows git bash: `python scriptname.py`

Comment: I would create a new file with a different name and try to open that one. See if it works properly. Then edit that file to see if you can reproduce the error or not.

Comment: I would have to think its a corrupt excel file.  Excel does some versioning for recovery purposes.  Doubt very much its on the pandas/xlrd side of things.

Comment: Stupid Windows 8/Excel 2013, I reopened the file again (for the third time) and it was back to it's original data. Remade my changes and now it is fine...

Comment: I have something that's probably similar. I open an image file with python (with PIL or cv2) and it loads an old version of the file. Everything else (eog, geeqie) shows me the image how it is supposed to be now. Is there any kind of caching/buffering in the file accesses of python? Some handle that can get stuck?